# 50s/60s short story, scientist invents a device linking the minds of asylum patients, therapy seems successful but several characters jump out windows

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Search for the title of a short (possibly 'short short') story from the 1950s or 1960s. I cannot remember the author.

A scientist/psychiatrist invents a device that allows him to link to the mind of patients in an asylum, for purposes of therapy. He does so. Coming out of the first session, he is ebullient at what seemed to be a total success, the patient appears to be recovering. While describing this to his colleagues, one of them walks to a window and jumps out.

Cut; the scientist wakes up again. Is re-assured that everything is fine.
Another character jumps out the window (or something as irrational).

Comment: What's the punchline here? Was the psychiatrist secretly suicidal?

Comment: @Valorum At first, I was thinking: "The device switches the neuroses and psychoses of the patient over into the brain of some other staff member, even though the latter is not conveniently hooked up to the device at the time." That doesn't explain the bit about the inventor waking up as if from a bad dream, though. Just as a wild thought: This sounds like the sort of thing that Philip K. Dick might write?

Comment: Was it one of the psychiatrists colleagues that jumped from the window or one of the patients?  From the wording in the question it could be either..

Comment: This rings a vague bell. The psychiatrist has been trapped in the patient's mind and when they think they have emerged and the session is over it isn't. Along the lines of Zelazny's *The Dream Master* or Silverberg's *A Sea of Faces*. The trouble is that around the time the New Wave broke there were a lot of stories along these lines.